# Sequence contains no Element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, dotnetopenauth

I have did the Google Login using `DotNetOpenAuth` and it was working fine, but all the sudden i was getting the exception on

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +269
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) +250

[ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found.]
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) +296
   OpenIDGoogleLogin.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +4626
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

But some times it works fine. I am not getting what would be issue for this. Please check the issue where i am getting the exception.

```
string discoveryUri = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id";
OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
string queryString = "";
var b = new UriBuilder(Request.Url) { Query = queryString };
var req = openid.CreateRequest(discoveryUri, b.Uri, b.Uri);
var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
req.AddExtension(fetchRequest);
req.RedirectToProvider();
```

Comment: You should show the code which produces the stack trace, namely `OpenIDGoogleLogin.Page_Load`

Comment: Updated the code in my question. Please have a look over it.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062322/google-openid-no-openid-endpoint-found-intermittent, it is caused by the web server being unable to contact Google, either due to time out or faulty DNS.  In some hosting environments, communications from the web server may be blocked or requires a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

this error comes because no element in your list and your trying to use single.
check if list is null before using or make sure your list should contains at least one element.

Comment: -1: you shouldn't mindlessy use `SingleOrDefault` just because you get a `Sequence contains no elements` exception. First you must understand *why* you're getting the exception, *then* you can know how to fix it. Maybe it's correct that there *must* always be a single element.

Comment: you are correct albireo , I've corrected the answer

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was due to a inability of the web application to contact Google (ASP.NET using Google OpenId needs to talk to www.google.com/accounts directly and not simply 302 redirections).

I was hosting on 1and1.  Applications running on 1and1 IIS cannot directly contact web sites located not on the same server.  I have been using a proxy provided by them all this time.  My web application needs both Google and another WCF web service located on another 1and1 url.  Suddenly, out of the blue, the WCF service stopped working unless I removed the 1and1 proxy.  But removing the proxy meant Google could not be contacted.

So I put back the 1and1 proxy but modified the WCF binding config to bypass the proxy, and authentication using Google Accounts worked again!

Hope this gives a clue to help you troubleshoot your situation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: Exposing Asp.Net controller as Soap and Wcf with a tunner, i need to implement a new adapter. But i forget to write "

> ServiceContract

" attribute to the interface. It has worked like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRESAdapterService
{
    [return: XmlElement("GetCategoriesResponse")]
    [OperationContract(Action = "urn:GetCategories")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]
    [FaultContract(typeof(RESAdapterServiceFault))]
    Task<CategoryResponse> GetCategoriesRequest();
}
```